# v-if to toggle message is resulting in infinite update loop Vue warning

Tags: vue.js

I am learning Vue Native, specifically the `v-if` conditional, and have the following test code:

```js
<template>
  <view class="container">
      <button :on-press="seen = !seen" title="Click to Toggle Message Visibility" />
      <text v-if="seen">Now you see the message</text>        
  </view>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      seen: false
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.container {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
</style>
```

It is supposed to let the user click the button and the message is to appear/disappear.  However, it is resulting in the following error:
**console.error: "[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.
 (found in )"**

How should the code be modified so it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that vue is treating `:on-press="seen = !seen"` like a binding so it always executes the expression on render. The rendering is modifying the state, hence causing an infinite loop.

I think you just need to extract it in a function.

```html
<template>
    <view class="container">
        <button :on-press="onPress" title="Click to Toggle Message Visibility" />
        <text v-if="seen">Now you see the message</text>        
    </view>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      seen: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onPress() {
      this.seen = !this.seen;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.container {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the accepted answer. In addition, the `:on-press` is an attribute binding, but using `v-on` event binding will not have this infinite loop issue, for example, like `<button v-on:click="seen = !seen" title="Click to Toggle Message Visibility" />`. That's probably where you get this inline method usage `seen = !seen` from.

Comment: Ah ha!  This is a helpful explanation.  However, when I changed the button code to the line you provided and stripped out the `onPress()` method logic, the "infinite update loop" error was not displayed but clicking the button does not toggle the message.  Why would that be?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Vue native `:on-press` binding, but could you try add some debugging code to the `onPress()` method, something like `alert()`. I suspect the method is not triggered by clicking.